# Sending income and lottery prizes to Tamilnadu, India from Singapore

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, singapore, lottery

I recently came to Singapore from Tamilnadu (India) for a 12 month project assignment and will be earning amount in SGD in Singapore. I came to Singapore via Employment Pass (EP).

I have two questions:

1. The earnings that I get in Singapore is taxed in Singapore. I want to send the amount to India by remittance service to my earlier savings bank account. Would I need to pay tax in India as well?
2. I got a lottery amount of around $2000 SGD. The amount is not taxable in Singapore. If I want to send the amount to India, would it be taxable? Also, lottery is banned in Tamilnadu. Is it okay to send the money to a bank account that I hold in Tamilnadu?

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned the dates when you left India. Taxability is not depended on whether you transfer the funds to India or NOT. It is dependent on whether you are NRI for tax purposes for the given financial year.

Refer to this question for more details
[Will it be taxable if I transfer money from UK account to India account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/will-it-be-taxable-if-i-transfer-money-from-uk-account-to-india-account/37257#37257)

Edit:
The lottery earnings are also treated in the same way. If you are NRI, you don't pay tax. Else you pay tax

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could anyone help me on the second question regarding lottery prize ?